# How can I call private method and pass parameters

Tags: java

I am doing  an assignment but I am stuck on this step. How would 
I Call the findInstructor method passing the instrFirst and 
     instrLast parameters to find the Instructor teaching the 
     course"? how do I call a  method that is private. any suggestion would be helpful thx

```
private Instructor findInstructor(String instrFirst, String instrLast){
}

public void addCourse(String crseNumber, int credits, String instrFirst, 
String instrLast)
{

" Call the findInstructor method passing the instrFirst and 
 instrLast parameters to find the Instructor teaching the 
 course"
}
```

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Just use reflection.

Comment: Both methods are instance methods in the same class, so calling a private method is fine. Give it a try! Weaver - no need for hacks like that.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have, it's very simple

```
private Instructor findInstructor(String instrFirst, String instrLast){
}

public void addCourse(String crseNumber, int credits, String instrFirst, 
String instrLast)
{
   Instructor instructor = findInstructor(instrFirst,instrLast);

}
```

findInstructor method must be in the same class as the addCourse method.

Answer (score 0):

Private access means that you can call this method only if you are inside of the same class as that method. You are unable to access that method from outside of the class containing it.

These two parameters you are asked to pass have to be included in the list of parameters of the method `addCourse()`. Inside of its body you then use references names  included in the list of parameters of `addCourse()` to pass them as arguments to the `findInstructor()` method (in your example it is `instrFirst` and 'instrLast' - the same as in `findInstructor()` list of arguments but it could be anything, it doesn't have to match references names exactly, because these names are used only locally, just the type of arguments must be the same).

The proper way to call that method inside of other method is the following:

```
public void addCourse(String crseNumber, int credits, String instrFirst, String instrLast) {
    /* the next line means that you assign the result of calling the findInstructor() method to variable instr */
    Instructor instr = findInstructor(instrFirst, instrLast)
}
```